# Iptables flush does not work

Tags: centos, iptables, centos-7

I am trying to make counters 0 for a specific ip chain.This is the command I used.

```
iptables --zero mychain
```

This was the official command given in [netfilter MAN page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html). But this does not make counters zero.

I am using Centos-7 3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64

Edit : (after vera's comment)
`iptables --zero mychain -L`

Output:

```
Chain mychain (3 references) 
target prot opt source destination 
ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere quota: 7340032000 bytes 
DROP   all -- anywhere anywhere
```

Comment: can you provide the result of command `iptables --zero mychain -L` ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot some parameters in the command : we do not see counters. Could you execute `iptables -nvxL mychain && iptables --zero mychain && iptables -nvxL` to show up counters immediately before and after the reset ?

Comment: @vera I executed above command and nothing happend. counters were not set to zero.